# Why some async methods have async while other don't

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asynchronous

I am trying to understand when to use await/async.
After reading few articles on the internet I have started to analyse Asp.Net Identity source code. Here is interesting fragment of RoleStore.cs

https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/RoleStore.cs

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Find a role by name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="roleName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task<TRole> FindByNameAsync(string roleName)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        return _roleStore.EntitySet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Name.ToUpper() == roleName.ToUpper());
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Insert an entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="role"></param>
    public virtual async Task CreateAsync(TRole role)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        if (role == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("role");
        }
        _roleStore.Create(role);
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync().WithCurrentCulture();
    }
```

My question is:
Why `FindByNameAsync` doesn't have async keyword while `CreateAsync` has?

We could write like this

```
 public async Task<TRole> FindByNameAsync(string roleName)
     {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        return await _roleStore.EntitySet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Name.ToUpper() == roleName.ToUpper());
    }
```

and this would compile. I assume this is incorrect but I don't know why.

Comment: Because the `FindByNameAsync ` doesn't `await` anything while the `CreateAsync` does.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use the keyword `async` when you use the keyword `await` in the code. Your first code snippet does not use `await` so there is no need for the `async`.

The reason the 2nd snippit is using `await` is likely the `.WithCurrentCulture();` method is doing something special so that the `SynchronizationContext` that the `await` in the method will use will have some kind of culture information stored within it.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't marked as `async` because it needs no `await`.

Yes, you *could* mark it as `async` and `await` the task.  it wouldn't *break* anything (well, it does subtly change the error handling semantics when called on a disposed object), but there's no reason to do it either.  You're going out of your way to add work that accomplishes nothing productive.